# Did BitGo terminate its "BitGO instant" service? Why?

Tags: bitgo

[This is the launch announcement](https://blog.bitgo.com/bitgo-instant-the-on-chain-solution-for-instant-bitcoin-commerce-surpasses-10-000-btc-transacted-65040cd48d3a).

https://www.bitgo.com/instant is a dead link now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure, as I don't use the service, but the current page appears to be here: https://www.bitgo.com/info/solutions#instant .  It's linked in the Solutions menu on the header of every page, so they're not hiding it.